# Dealing with FAR pointers in code library for multiple embedded platforms

Tags: c, embedded

I'm trying to maintain a library of code, with samples, for multiple embedded platforms.  I need to support the concept of "far" (non 16-bit) pointers for some function parameters.

I thought I had a good solution with defining the macro `FAR` to be `__far` on some platforms and nothing on platforms with 32-bit pointers (embedded Linux, Win32, etc.).  With that macro, I could easily define pointers as `somestruct_t FAR *foo`.

But then I started working with Freescale processors, and their compiler requires the `FAR` to go **between** the asterisk and variable name. (`somestruct_t * __far foo`).

The best solution I've come up with to handle this case is to define a macro `FARPTR` as either `__far *`, `* __far` or just `*` depending on the platform.  This allows for `somestruct_t FARPTR foo`.

Are there cleaner solutions out there?  **In particular, I don't like that there isn't a `*` visible to someone reading that code.**  I'm also worried that I will run into problems when it comes to function declarations.  Get a load of this syntax from the Freescale compiler help:

```
int __far *f();          // __far function returning a pointer to int
int * __far f();         // Function returning a __far pointer to int
int __near * __far f();  // __near function returning a __far pointer to int
```

That last one kills me -- a qualifier **inside** of the return type indicates a near function?!  And I've recently learned that adding the `__near` isn't enough to actually compile a function to near memory -- I need to wrap it in pragmas.

So, has anyone seen a nicer solution than my `FARPTR` macro idea?

Comment: Is your embedded system really so constrained that you can't just compile with the "large" model and make all pointers far? That's the cleanest solution.

Comment: This syntax seems to mirror the way `const` works with pointers, with `__near` mirroring C++'s `mutable`. It doesn't seem very alien to me.

Comment: Can't your original idea of defining `FAR` to `__far` (and similar for `NEAR`) still work?  You just have to make sure the `FAR`/`NEAR` go where the Freescale compiler wants them (like it or not).  On other platforms those macros will be whitespace, so where they're used in the declarations is of no concern for them.

Comment: @R: Not all of the embedded platforms I've worked with support a "large" model.  @Michael Burr: the problem is that I need to support some platforms that require the `__far` before `*` and some that require it after.

Comment: @larsmans: it's not odd that `__near` is related to the function and not its return type?

Comment: @larsman: applying the `__near`/`__far` attribute to a function would seem more natural to me if it came at the end of the declaration (similar to how `const` can be applied to a member function in C++). So the first declaration from the examples might look like `int * f() __far;` to indicate that "`f` is a far function that returns a pointer to `int`".  I wonder if the compiler in question would accept that?

Comment: @tomlogic: I didn't think that was a consideration... that's a bit of a bind.

Comment: @Michael Burr: it's quite unfortunate that the compiler doesn't accept `__far` after the parameter list or before the return type.  Looks like my `FARPTR` is going to be the way to go.

Comment: Are you sure that the compilers that support the first syntax do not also support the Freescale syntax?  i.e. it may be possible to standardise on that.

Comment: @tomlogic: The `__near` being related to the function is acting like a `extern` or `static` - the `__far` related to the pointer is acting like `const` or `restrict`.

Comment: @caf: I totally get that, but it would make more sense to me if the `__near` came **before** the `int`.  I think of the `int * __far` as the return type.  To insert a qualifier related the function's location in memory seems crazy.

Comment: @tomlogic: It seems likely that `__near int * __far func()` would work too, and mean the same thing (in the same way that both `extern int foo();` and `int extern foo();` mean the same thing).

Comment: @caf: I so wish that alternate syntax would work, but sadly no.  I've tried it there and after the parameter list and the compiler generates errors each way.  `int __near * __far f()` is the only valid syntax for a near function that returns a far pointer to int. :-(

Comment: sounds like you need FAR(type) macro rather than just FAR macro.

Answer (score 2):

The freescale processor's usage is more consistent with standard type qualifiers such as `const`, that placement causes it to refer to the pointer not the data being pointed to.  That said, since "*far data*" rather than a "*far pointer*" would be meaningless, you'd have thought that it would not matter, but greater consistency presumably makes for a simpler compiler parser.

You could use something kludgey such as:

```
#if defined __SOME_ARCHITECTURE__

    #define DECLARE_FARPTR( type, identifier ) type __far * identifier

#if defined __SOME_OTHER_ARRCHITECTURE__

    #define DECLARE_FARPTR( type, identifier ) type * __far identifier

#else

    #define DECLARE_FARPTR( type, identifier )

#endif
```

Then your declarations would look like:

```
DECLARE_FARPTR( somestruct_t, foo ) ;
```

or in a function prototype taking a pointer parameter:

```
void fn( DECLARE_FARPTR( somestruct_t, foo )  ) ;
```

or a function returning a far pointer:

```
DECLARE_FARPTR( somestruct_t, fn( void ) ) ;
```

As you can see it quickly gets hard to read and a *declarative function-like macro* is generally a thing best avoided.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a specific better solution for you.  However, having dealt with the same problem on several occasions, I recommend a review of the [AUTOSAR](http://autosar.org/index.php?p=3&up=1&uup=2&uuup=7&uuuup=0&uuuuup=0) [Specification of Compiler Abstraction (PDF)](http://autosar.org/download/R4.0/AUTOSAR_SWS_CompilerAbstraction.pdf).

It includes a detailed approach to dealing with multiple compilers.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Clifford's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297672/dealing-with-far-pointers-in-code-library-for-multiple-embedded-platforms/6298951#6298951), although function-like macros are probably a bad idea, you could use a macro to create typedefs:

```
#ifdef SOME_ARCH
#define DEF_FAR_PTR(type, farptr_typename) typedef type __far *farptr_typename;
#elsif SOME_OTHER_ARCH
#define DEF_FAR_PTR(type, farptr_typename) typedef type * __far farptr_typename;
#else
#define DEF_FAR_PTR(type, farptr_typename) typedef type * farptr_typename;
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I also work with Freescale and my own solution to this is either of the following:

1) Replace far pointers with plain integers when possible. This doesn't work in every situation, but is particularly useful when dealing with function pointers, for example when writing interrupt vector tables.

2) Instead of using far pointers, write code that is *identical* to what the compiler will produce during a far pointer access. Here is an example for a Freescale MCU:

```
unsigned char readFromPage (unsigned char page, const unsigned char* address) 
{   
  unsigned char value;   
  unsigned char tmp = PPAGE;

  SAFE_DisableInterrupts;
    PPAGE = page;
    value = *address;
    PPAGE = tmp;
  SAFE_EnableInterrupts;

  return value; 
}
```

(this code may be inlined depending on the case)

3) Use #pragmas as far as possible.

As a result, I don't have a single far or near pointer in my code, it is portable (as portable as hardware-related code gets), and I can check it with static analysers that only understand standard C.

Comment: The rationale behind this is: too many programmers blindly use what's handed to them, standard or not. Particularly true for embedded programmers. Try to think outside the pre-made box instead: far pointers aren't standard, nor are they consistent, reliable or well-defined. They are a notable hazard to your program, especially if it is ported. Think thrice before introducing any form of non-standard syntax in your C program!

Answer (score 0):

It might just be cleaner to define two FAR macros: one for before the * and another for after the *.

Comment: Ew.  `void FAR1 * FAR2 foo;`?  I'm sticking with `void FARPTR foo;` and defining `FARPTR` to either `*`, `__far *` or `* __far` depending on the platform.  This allows for `void FARPTR FARPTR foo;` for pointers to pointers.